# Dropbox without AsyncTask class

Tags: android-asynctask, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using following function to download file from Dropbox.It runs perfectly when i call the async class to download file.But giving error when i call on normal class to download file with "Failed to download"

```
 public void dropboxcopy()
    {
  SharedPreferences prefernces = getSharedPreferences("Drop", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor_first = prefernces.edit();
        String first_time_login= prefernces.getString("FirstRun",null);


        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            editor_first.putString("FirstRun","Yes");
            editor_first.commit();
            dropbox.getSession().startAuthentication(Update_Database.this);
       }
        else {
            DownloadFileFromDropbox download = new DownloadFileFromDropbox(this, dropbox,
                    FILE_DIR,myInternalFile);
            download.execute();

        }

    }
```

Async Class File:

```
public class DownloadFileFromDropbox extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GirviDrop";
    private DropboxAPI<?> dropbox;
    private String path;
    private Context context;
    private Boolean fileexist;
    private File internal;

    public DownloadFileFromDropbox(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> dropbox,
                               String path,File internal) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.dropbox = dropbox;
        this.path = path;
        this.internal=internal;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

          if(internal.exists())
            {
               internal.delete();
                internal.createNewFile();
            }

            Entry existingentry= dropbox.metadata( path ,1000,null,true,null);


            if (existingentry.contents.size() != 0)
            {
                for (Entry ent :existingentry.contents)
                {
                    String name = ent.fileName();
                    if(name.equals(DATABASE_NAME))
                    {    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(internal);
                         dropbox.getFile(path + DATABASE_NAME, null, outputStream, null);

                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (result) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "File Downloaded Successfully from dropbox!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if(fileexist=true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "databse not present on app!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Download file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code runs perfectly....

Modified Code:

```
 public void dropboxcopy()
    {
  SharedPreferences prefernces = getSharedPreferences("Drop", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor_first = prefernces.edit();
        String first_time_login= prefernces.getString("FirstRun",null);


        if (!isLoggedIn) {
            editor_first.putString("FirstRun","Yes");
            editor_first.commit();
            dropbox.getSession().startAuthentication(Update_Database.this);
       }
        else {

            DownFile dd=new DownFile(this, dropbox,FILE_DIR,myInternalFile);
            Boolean result=dd.exe();
            if (result) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "File Downloaded Successfully from dropbox!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Download file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "after login previously", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
```

Normal Class File:

```
public class DownFile  {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GirviDrop";
    private DropboxAPI<?> dropbox;
    private String path;
    private Context context;
    private Boolean fileexist;
    private File internal;

    public DownFile(Context context, DropboxAPI<?> dropbox,
                        String path,File internal) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.dropbox = dropbox;
        this.path = path;
        this.internal=internal;
    }


    public boolean exe() {

        try {
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

          if(internal.exists())
            {
                internal.delete();
                internal.createNewFile();
            }

            Entry existingentry= dropbox.metadata( path ,1000,null,true,null);


            if (existingentry.contents.size() != 0)
            {
                for (Entry ent :existingentry.contents)
                {
                    String name = ent.fileName();
                    if(name.equals(DATABASE_NAME))
                    {    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(internal);
                        dropbox.getFile(path + DATABASE_NAME, null, outputStream, null);

                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NetworkOnMainThreadException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
        return false;
    }


 }
```

Error:

"Failed to download File" which means exe() returning false.

LogCat:

```
07-15 18:58:55.673    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-15 18:58:55.673    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
07-15 18:58:55.673    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
07-15 18:58:55.673    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
07-15 18:58:55.673    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
07-15 18:58:55.674    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-15 18:58:55.674    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-15 18:58:55.674    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-15 18:58:55.674    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-15 18:58:55.674    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-15 18:58:55.677    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-15 18:58:55.678    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-15 18:58:55.679    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:387)
07-15 18:58:55.679    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:339)
07-15 18:58:55.679    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.streamRequest(RESTUtility.java:194)
07-15 18:58:55.679    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.request(RESTUtility.java:124)
07-15 18:58:55.679    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.metadata(DropboxAPI.java:1919)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.DownFile.exe(DownFile.java:49)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Update_Database.dropboxcopy(Update_Database.java:181)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Update_Database.Update_data(Update_Database.java:140)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at loginscreen.example.com.girviapp.Update_Database.onButtonClicker124(Update_Database.java:126)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
07-15 18:58:55.687    2311-2311/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
07-15 18:58:55.774    2311-2330/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-15 18:58:55.774    2311-2330/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa00264e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-15 18:58:59.297    2311-2330/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-15 18:58:59.298    2311-2330/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa00264e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Comment: Error :"Failed to Download file"
which means exe() returning false

Comment: What's the actual error causing `exe` to return `false`? It looks like you're catching several errors and just printing the stack trace, so there should be something useful in your log.

Comment: I have edited question with logcat

Comment: So the error is "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". Searching for that should help.

Comment: Yea, documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html Just like it says in the exception name, you're making a network connection on the main thread (which you shouldn't do).

Comment: It runs perfectly in AsyncTask class using this class to download file.But if i have to perform some operation on that file in dropboxcopy() function it might happen that file is taking time to download and my function executing line of code on that file giving error file not present means not downloaded.So what i need is to fully execute asynctask with post execute function then execute following code of dropboxcopy().